# Chat Application - Trouble Connecting to Server from Client

Tags: c++, networking, client-server, chat

I have written a simple c++ server/client chat application. I am interested in being able to have multiple clients speak to one another through the server (like a chat room). I would like this to be able to work over the internet and not just within my local network.

I am having trouble connecting to the server (the server is running on my desktop machine at home, which is connected via a wire to the modem).

The server has the following socket address settings:

```
addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
addr.sin_port        = htons(1234);
addr.sin_family      = AF_INET;
```

The client has the following socket address settings:

```
addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("63.22.45.56");
addr.sin_port        = htons(1234);
addr.sin_family      = AF_INET;
```

I used the internet WAN IP Address of the desktop for the client to connect to.
I port forwarded "1234" in my router settings for both TCP/UDP. It is also pointing to the local IP address of my desktop (192.168.0.16)

I am not sure why it is not able to connect. Please feel free to look at my client and server code below.

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/12735155/chat_client.cpp  (Note: the socket address is 127.0.0.1 here, but ignore that. I have updated it to 63.22.45.56)

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/12735155/chat_server.cpp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should specify 192.168.0.16 in your code instead of 127.0.0.1.

This is because you do not want to listen on localhost, you want to listen on the IP address connected to the outside world. That's why this code will work when you tell the client to connect to localhost, but it won't work if you tell your client to connect to your WAN IP and the connection gets routed outside.